# How to thank a teacher in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, writing-style, acknowledgement

Given that a student wants to thank you her teacher for her assistance to her project thesis, is it polite if she writes any of this at the end of her thesis:

1. Thanks to your assistance, my project was done under your supervision.
2. You have been my project's tutor. Now it is done successfully, thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, what I wrote was partly humor, partly serious:

> "I would like to thank: Prof. [my adviser] for his advice and support
>   throughout the thesis work, Prof. [] for his patience as I
>   mis-implemented his design, [] for his assistance in selecting
>   components, the [lab and department] for computer time, [], whose
>   Masters thesis provided the format I have adopted, the manufacturers
>   of [caffeinated beverages] for their stimulating ideas, E. Gary Gygax
>   for giving me something to kill, and the States of Alaska and
>   Confusion."

I think you're overthinking this. Any polite statement crediting those who have made a significant contribution to the project will be fine.

Suggestion: see if your school maintains copies of past theses in their library, read through a few to see what other people have done, and adopt what seems useful from those.

Comment: My thesis has an acknowledgements section in the front matter. Likely, your institutions have guidelines about the appropriate location, length, and content of acknowledgements.

Comment: Likely, but not necessarily. Ask your advisor or other professors, investigate (I've given you a pointer to a good resource), and proceed appropriately.